# Org-capture-template which add a ID property

Tags: org-mode

I set up the org-capture-template as

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("d" "Diary" plain
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-today-headline) "\n%?")
        ("p" "Procedure" item
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-procedures-headline) "%i%?")
))
```

When insert a plan, it seems working properly.

[image]

Unfortunately, after strike "C-c C-c" to finalize the capturing, an ID property will be appended automatically to the heading as

```
** Procedures
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       ea33d47e-db77-471a-b5d3-60546248272d
:END:
- Question about "How to delete the properties automatically inserted? "
```

I referenced the [Capture-template](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Capture-templates) for "template-elments", "template expansions" and "template in contexts", but did not find variables which define how to add a ID property.

I don't want the ID property, where could I cancel it from appending automatically?

Comment: Do you also see this with `emacs -Q`? What is the value of `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook`?

Comment: Also, what is the value of  `org-insert-heading-hook`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook
  #'org-id-get-create)
```